# Fire click event once per (different) class

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to have a click event fire on any tag with the same class only once.

I tried using '.one', although, it removes itself after the first class tag is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $(".dropdown").one('click', function() { 
        ...
    });
});
```

The code is bought in from another .php file on the same directory with some server information so there are multiple (no end) in the number of tags with the same class.

```
<div class = \"dropdown\" id=" . $row["name"] . "dropdown" . ">
                    <div>". $row["email"] . "</div>
                    <div>name:" . $row["name"] ."</div>
                    <div>". $row["email"] ."</div></div>
                    ";
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Little unclear - do you have multiple tags with one class or one tag with multiple classes?  If multiple tags, only one them to be clicked?   If multiple classes allow the tag to be clicked for each class?

Comment: "Fire click event" / `.one("click")` - these are two different scenarios.  *Fire click* would be `$(".dropdown").trigger("click")` while `.one("click"` would be *handle click event*.   Which are you trying to do?

Comment: require: *"once per class"* / issue: *"removes itself after clicked"* - your "issue" is a description of your requirement - ie what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have multiple tags with the same class. I want to add info to each of those tags on click but only one time.

Comment: What sort of "info" do you want to add?  Might be simpler to check if the "info" has already been added, maybe adding/removing another class.  You might be able to do this with event delegation, but hard to tell what your expecting to happen when the user clicks again.  Or you could have a different click handler for when you "*still need to be able to click the tag for other purposes*"

Comment: Can you provide a before/after example?

Comment: If a user clicks, information below the 'user' that is clicked will appear (with unique data from the server). Clicking again simply hides and shows the information. I was planning to create another toggle click event for that though.

Comment: I see how that relates to your php snippet.  Does the email/name etc exist when the page loads or is it loaded only when you first click?  Easiest solution appears to be two handlers, the loading one with `.one` and a 2nd for toggle (show a placeholder while loading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments what you actually needs to do is apply a check of text available already or not?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $(".dropdown").on('click', function() { 
       if(empty($('<text wrapper class or id>').text())){
           // add code to bring the info
       }
       //rest other code.
    });
});
```

Note : I fyou can show your code HTML then I can Update my code to give you concreete answer. The above will guide you how to proceed.

Comment: Yeah, like I didn't want to complicate the question too much but I am planning on using a toggle to hide/show the information once it has been brought in.

Comment: Thank you. So I check if either the class is empty or exists, otherwise run the toggle. I can go off that. Much appreciated.